# MPI rodando junto com Gurobi

Tags: c++

Estou tentando fazer um simples código em c++ o qual tem como objetivo executar 1 milhão de PL (programação linear) com o otimizador gurobi utilizando processamento paralelo MPI.

O problema é que ao usar o MPI e o Gurobi (versão estudantil) juntos, por algum motivo o programa para de executar corretamente. Então, Debuguei o programa, comentei linha por linha e constatei que o problema vem quando eu tento criar o ambiente do gurobi env = new GRBEnv();. Abaixo eu coloquei uma parte do código. No código, eu simplesmente jogo na tela o numero do processo, contudo, quando eu tento criar o ambiente do gurobi, o programa não funciona mais, ele não da erro, mas parece que fica em stand-by uns 5 segundos e finaliza, sendo que o procedimento correto seria jogar na tela o número dos processos. No código abaixo, supostamente criar o ambiente do gurobi fica sem sentido, uma vez que eu não estou otimizando nada, mas deveria funcionar mesmo assim. A implementação da otimização será o próximo passo.

Alguém já viu algo parecido?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include "gurobi_c++.h"

void main(){ 

GRBEnv *env = 0;
// cria um ambiente para o gurobi.
env = new GRBEnv();

int NumProcs, NumId;


MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NumProcs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NumId);

cout << NumProcs;

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo(a) ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Depois edite a sua pergunta para fornecer detalhes da sua dificuldade. Caso contrário, ninguém conseguirá te ajudar.

Comment: você consegue compilar algum programa usando apenas o gurobi ?

Comment: @Felipe consigo, o Gurobi já uso a algum tempo.. Eu consigo rodar também programas apenas com o MPI.. O problema me parece que eh quando os dois estão juntos.